# Mode Spatial Filter

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification, post-processing, spatial-filter

I want to run a Mode filter (for example: 3*3 pixel) on the classification result in Google Earth Engine. But I can not find the command of this filter.

Answer (score 2):

`ee.Image.focalMode()`

You can find the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-focalmode).